# Can I import my old podcast MP3s into iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

The title pretty much says it all.

If I have 25 podcast MP3s, how can I associate them with the podcast in iTunes?

Answer (score 9):

In iTunes it's possible to label items as Podcasts. To do so:

1. Import your items into iTunes if not done already
2. Select them all and choose Get Info from either the contextual menu or the File menu
3. Go to the Options tab and set "Media Kind" to Podcast
4. It will then appear in the Podcasts section using the Album name as a group

Comment: What if these are old episodes of an existing podcast?

Comment: @John Gietzen No idea for sure. I think it should but give it a try!